# How to trim decimal?

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a decimal number :

```
decimal a = 0.8537056986486486486486486486;
```

I want to show it as string with only 8 digit after point :
a equals -> "0.85370569".
How can I do it ?

Comment: This page could help : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform this numerically you could use:

```
decimal a = (decimal) 0.8537056986486486486486486486;
String test = (Math.Truncate(100000000 * a) / 100000000).ToString();
```

Comment: Instead of casting you could also add the [flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals) `m` at the end of the number.

Answer (score 1):

For example, like this:

```
a.ToString("0.00000000");
```

Comment: This would round to *70

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
a.ToString("D8");
```

This should convert it to the correct format.

Edit:

As said in the comments, D is only used for integral types, thus not for decimals and such.
Use

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    decimal d = (decimal)0.8537056986486486486486486486;
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("N8"));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

instead.

This will format it to `0.85370570`

Comment: Isn't this only for integral types?

Comment: Not according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: @ThaMe90 Please read the description on msdn: "Supported by: Integral types only." Or, am I mistaken?

Comment: Could be that it is `a.ToString("N8");`, but I don't know for sure...

Comment: I tried using that with a `decimal` type but it throws an exception: "Format specifier was invalid."

Comment: Yeah, same here... I'll update the answer to use N instead of D...

Answer (score 0):

```
 decimal a = 0.8537056986486486486486486486;    
 var v=  a.ToString("#.########");
```